# How to change this particular "deep blue" color that displays?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I'd like to change the color of a certain character set displayed in my terminal.

I'm not sure if it's related to the terminal itself (xfce terminal) or to the colorscheme (distilled.vim) so I'm not sure how to target it properly. Could it be something tied directly to some sort of setting within the OS itself? (Lubuntu)

Here are some screenshots, the first two show what I'm talking about. It's the deep blue tilde `~` characters that denote the end of the file as well as the `....` line characters in the second image.

[image: end of file designations]

[image: .... designations]

[image: xfce color settings]

[image: distilled vim colorscheme]

The remaining images show my terminal color palette and my vim scheme, if they're of any use.

Nord https://github.com/arcticicestudio/nord-xfce-terminal

Distilled https://github.com/KKPMW/distilled-vim

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any insights!

---

**UPDATE**: Since the color of those characters is changed with other colorschemes, I suspect there is something I can target within vim to set the color. But looking through the many colorschemes I have, I don't know enough about them to know what I'm looking for...

Comment: Welcome back :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to set these elements to different colors by targeting these two highlight groups:

`EndOfBuffer`
`NonText`

So in my case, I added the following to my .vimrc, mirroring the way the colors are established within the distilled colorscheme's files:

```
hi clear EndOfBuffer
hi clear NonText

hi EndOfBuffer  ctermbg=0 ctermfg=8 cterm=NONE guibg=NONE    guifg=#6194ba gui=NONE
hi NonText      ctermbg=0 ctermfg=8 cterm=NONE guibg=NONE    guifg=#6194ba gui=NONE
```